# Fetch file in library (rollup)

Tags: javascript, webpack, widget, rollup

I'm building javascript library (more something like widget) which will have some UI within. I'm adding HTML elements to DOM by javascript. To add this HTML I have following code:

```
async insertWidgetMarkup() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('src/html/form.html')
        this.rootElement.innerHTML = await response.text()
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error gathering form HTML.', e)
    }
}
```

I build entire thing with rollup

```
// rollup.config.js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
    input: 'main.js',
    output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'cjs',
        name: 'search_widget.js'
    },
    plugins: [commonjs()]
};


// package.json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rollup --config --watch",
```

My issue is that in bundled file I have `await fetch('src/html/form.html');` therefore it won't work in other applications. Can I somehow tell rollup to resolve this so it will have HTML in bundled file? Or if no - what other options I have, what is typical approach for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of fetching, you can `import` the file directly with the [rollup-plugin-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-html).

Setup `rollup` config to use the plugin like this

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import html from 'rollup-plugin-html';

export default {
    input: 'main.js',
    output: {
        format: 'umd',
        name: 'search_widget',
        file: 'dist/search_widget.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        commonjs(),
        html({
            include: '**/*.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

Then in your source file, use import like this

```js
import html from 'src/html/form.html'

insertWidgetMarkup() {
    try {
        this.rootElement.innerHTML = html
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error gathering form HTML.', e)
    }
}
```

Rollup will bundle the html files now.